# AngularJS - Passing a function to spyOn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

SO I have this simple, watered-down app that returns the NATO alphabet and then does unit tests on it using mocks and promises.

**[HERE'S A LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IY0aUx6VDlMDIUBySZKU?p=preview)**

I'm trying to `spyOn` a function from my `.service()` of `MainModel`. In the controller, I have a deferred promise called `natoAlphabet` that successfully displays on the page.

At first, I was referencing `getNato` from the `MainController`, but I never set `MainController.getNato` to the `MainModel.getNato`.

So I added in the `MainController`:

```
this.getNato = MainModel.getNato;
```

And I get the error of: `Expected spy getNato to have been called.`

However, in the `console log`, if you do a console output of `mockMainCtrl` the controller being mocked inside the `beforeEach` near the top, you get `Object {name: "Hello World!", getNato: Promise}`

and then below inside the first `it()` test, the output is `Object {name: "Hello World!"}` however, if you expand that one, you get:

```
Object {name: "Hello World!"}
    getNato: Promise
    name: "Hello world!";
    __proto__: Object
```

Whereas the one inside the `beforeEach`, you had `getNato`.

## My error

My error happens when the Jasmine test runs and I get `Expected spy getNato to have been called.` from the line `expect(mockMainCtrl.getNato).toHaveBeenCalled();` on **theSpec.js**.

So what am I doing wrong?

I don't think there is anything wrong with **app.js** because the page can successfully read the promise.

## Appendix:

**theSpec.js**:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $scope, $q, mockMainCtrl, $controller, scope, deferred;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_, MainModel) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

    deferred = _$q_.defer();

    mockMainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      MainModel: MainModel
    });

    console.log(mockMainCtrl);
  }));

  it('spied and have been called', function() {
    spyOn(mockMainCtrl, 'getNato');
    console.log(mockMainCtrl);
    expect(mockMainCtrl.getNato).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('Name from service, instantiated from controller, to be mocked correctly', inject(function() {
    expect(mockMainCtrl.name)
      .toEqual("Hello World!");
  }));

  it('Get [getNato] mocked deferred promise', function(mainCtrl) {
    deferred.resolve([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.results).not.toBe(undefined);
    expect($scope.results).toEqual(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India']);
    expect($scope.error).toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('MainModel', function($q) {
  this.name = "Hello World!";

  var getNato = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var theNatoAlphabet = ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India'];
    deferred.resolve(theNatoAlphabet);
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.getNato = getNato();
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MainModel) {
  this.name = MainModel.name;

  var self = this;

  MainModel.getNato.then(function(data) {
    self.natoAlphabet = data;
    $scope.results = data;
  }).catch(function() {
    $scope.error = 'There has been an error!';
  });

  this.getNato = MainModel.getNato;


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at - http://plnkr.co/edit/57ZA8BXscmdY6oDX5IOA?p=preview.

You'd want to 'spyOn' the dependency i.e. the 'MainModel' here and do it before the '$controller' construction as the 'promise' is getting resolved on the construction of the controller. Hope this helps.

Something like -

```
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _MainModel_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    MainModel = _MainModel_;
    spyOn(MainModel, 'getNato').andCallThrough();
    mockMainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('spied and have been called', function() {
    expect(MainModel.getNato).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```